# What works for procrastination?

Tags: attention, procrastination

Procrastination seems universal and well understood by the public. However, there seems to be very little research into techniques and approaches that works to reduce and manage procrastination.

The previous aversion therapy thread cited a 2012 review that found minimal research into procrastination. It is 2019 now and I was wondering whether anyone knows of any recent research? - [Effectiveness of aversion therapy for procrastination](https://psychology.stackexchange.com/a/18477/21)

Another thread will address procrastination in ADHD - [Treatment and strategies for procrastination for ADHD](https://psychology.stackexchange.com/questions/23813/treatment-and-strategies-for-procrastination-for-adhd)

Answer (score 1):

I found this 2018 meta-analysis of 24 studies by Wendelienvan & Klingsieck on procrastination intervention - [Educational Research Review article.](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/327736834_Overcoming_Procrastination_A_Meta-Analysis_of_Intervention_Studies)

They used Steel's 2007 definition of procrastination as an irrational and acratic behavior. Procrastination is a voluntary delay an intended course of action despite expecting to be worse off for the delay. Wendelienvan & Klingsieck found that **cognitive-behavioural** therapeutic approaches had a greater reduction in procrastination than **self-regulation** and **strength & assertiveness training** interventions.

Quite an accessible and interesting read.

Comment: While you provided a research review paper giving such a definition, I don't necessarily agree that procrastination is always *"irrational and acratic behavior"* or voluntary. Procrastination can be involuntary in a sense whereby it is as a result of apathy developed through the after-effects of trauma or unresolved grief and loss.

Comment: True, but this is in the education setting Chris.

Comment: So, with respect, does that mean those in education cannot be affected by trauma, grief and loss?

Comment: It just means that the incidence of grief would be much lower for the usual young university student population compared to people seeing a therapist for example...